# How to convert text and time stamp column field to date in excel

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, format

I am facing issue to convert time stamp date to only date in excel which has text also in same column. Need to convert only time stamp part to date without removing the text content in excel. Can someone please help me with this ?

Example : `item migrated on 6/28/2020,8:34:26 PM`

Required output: `item migrated on 6/28/2020`

In the above example I need to convert only date with time stamp part to date.

Comment: is there always only one comma in the text and can we discard everything after the comma?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this always comes through with a consistent format, you could just drop everything to the right of the comma.

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1)-1)
```